# Problem with binding a property in UserControl to a property of one its Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have bound the `Text` property of a `TextBlock` in my `UserControl` to one of its dependency properties (DPs), and the initial binding works properly and the text is displayed. However, when the `FrameRate` property is updated later on, the change is not reflected in the `TextBlock`.

Here is the code for the binding in the `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl>
...
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UiView.FrameRate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
...
</UserControl>

    public UiView UiView
    {
        get => (UiView)GetValue(s_uiViewProperty);
        set => SetValue(s_uiViewProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty s_uiViewProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(UiView), typeof(UiView), typeof(UiViewPanel), new PropertyMetadata(OnUiViewPropertyChanged));
```

And here is the code for the `FrameRate` property, which is defined in the `UiView` class:

```
private readonly FrameRate m_frameRate = new FrameRate();

public double FrameRate => m_frameRate.Current;
```

I am sure that the `FrameRate` property is being updated, but the change is not reflected in the `TextBlock`. How can I fix this issue and ensure that the updated value of `FrameRate` is reflected in the `TextBlock`?

Comment: You're binding to a property of the object you have as a dependency property. That property needs to notify change. Either by being a dp itself or using inotifypropertychanged.

Comment: @Andy Thanks Andy, DP seems to work. I am not sure how inotifypropertychanged can be implemented in this case as DataContext comes from the parent of the user control